# How to show Notification when app close

Tags: android, mysql, service, android-volley, background-process

I need to check data from Mysql and show alert(notification) when data update  .Right now the notification working only when app is open but when app closed, it not work .How to solve this problem, could you help me ?

My code(Service.java)

```
public class Myservice2 extends Service {
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean finish = false;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    String showUrl = "http://test/readData.php";
    private static final String TAG = "ServiceDemo";
    final static String MY_ACTION = "MY_ACTION";
    private final long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 5000;
    private final IBinder mBinder = new MyBinder();
    String weightString ;
    private Timer timer= new Timer();
    private  int g=0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
         pollForUpdates();
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    }

private void pollForUpdates(){
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                displayData();
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(MY_ACTION);
                intent.putExtra("DATAPASSED", g);
                sendBroadcast(intent);

            }catch (Exception e){

            }
        }
    },0,UPDATE_INTERVAL);
}
     /*------------------------- get data-----------------------*/
    public void displayData() {

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            showUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            System.out.println(response.toString());
            try {
                JSONArray scale = response.getJSONArray("scale");
                for (int i = 0; i < scale.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject scale = scale.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = scale.getString("id");
                    if(id.equals("00001")) {
                        String weight = scale.getString("weight");                    
                        g=Integer.parseInt(weight);
                        if(g==1 && !noti){
                            PushNotification();
                            noti=true;
                        }else if(g!=1 && noti){
                            noti=false;
                        }
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.append(error.getMessage());

        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

    }

    public void PushNotification()
    {
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,notificationIntent,0);

        //set
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name);
        builder.setContentText("Contents");
        builder.setContentTitle("title");
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);

        Notification notification = builder.build();
        nm.notify((int)System.currentTimeMillis(),notification);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(timer!=null){
           timer.cancel();
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mBinder;
    }
 public  class  MyBinder extends Binder{
     Myservice2 getService(){
         return Myservice2.this;
     } }

}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {  
    private Myservice2 service2;
    MyReceiver myReceiver;
    TextView weighttxt;

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       weighttxt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_currentweight);   
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {  
        myReceiver = new MyReceiver();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(MyService.MY_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,com.thebestsolution.servicemysql.Myservice2.class);
        startService(intent);
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
     super.onStop();
        unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
        super.onStop();

    }
    private class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            int datapassed = arg1.getIntExtra("DATAPASSED", 0);
           weighttxt.setText(""+datapassed);
        }
   }
    private void  doBinService(){
        ServiceConnection cn;
        cn=new ServiceConnection() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
                service2=((Myservice2.MyBinder)service).getService();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(service2!=null){
                    String weight=service2.getWeightString();
                     }
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                service2=null;

            }

        };

        Intent i=new Intent(this,Myservice2.class);
        bindService(i, cn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

@Override
protected void onResume() {

   Log.d("activity", "onResume");
    if (service2 == null) {
        doBinService();
    }
    super.onResume();
}

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (service2 != null) {
           // unbindService(myConnection);
            service2 = null;
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

}
```

Comment: please post your code where you attempt to do this

Comment: How are you updating MySql data?

Comment: it reload data from MySQL (server) by service